# Is C platform (H/W + S/W) dependent or independent

Tags: c, gcc

If you write a C program using all the standard C libraries that are common to all platforms, be it Unix (any flavor) or Windows, (ie stdio.h, math.h etc.), and compile it using a standard compiler (ie GCC) and run it on any one of the same CPU arch, why wouldn't the binary run across different machines matching all the above criteria?

When I compile a C program on my X86 Mac, using only standard libraries, why can't that compiled binary run under Linux or Windows on the same CPU architecture?

Is it because during C runtime there is platform specific library linking that takes place or what?

Comment: This is a wall of text and you scream at the end. This is not the way to format a question.

Comment: My eyes hurt...  please sort out the formatting

Comment: This is the most poorly formatted question I've ever seen on SO. You deserve an award.

Comment: just in case you didn't know: most internet users will probably consider exhaustive uppercase usage shouting. You'd likely receive more serious answers if you'd change that since most people don't really enjoy being shouted at.

Comment: You may be writing OS agnostic code, but the libs used by the compiler aren't. Ex: `printf` calls an OS specific function to write to the console.

Comment: @Johnny different implementations aren't really a binary portability problem. In the case of `printf`, it forms an interface to shield off these details. If there is binary compatibility at the interface level, the underlying implementation would not matter.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp well printf internally calls fprintf function.. And it is a part of stdio.h library which is definitely platform agnostic.And fprintdf too is a standard built-in routine common to C platform. Even if GCC itself has some of its own libraries to link during the build, I'm using it as standard compiler and runtime on all the other machines running other OSes. So whats the issue? Does fprintf further do a platform specific system call (OS X in my case) which cannot be resolved on other OSes coz on those systems the runtime would go looking for them and not find them?? I'm confused..

Comment: @crashmstr sorry man i had the CAPS LOCK on by mistake while typing.. I should have been careful..Won't happen again..

Comment: @rahulbsb You should also lay off the **bold**. You're overusing it badly. When in doubt, *don't* bold your text. Most posts don't need to contain any bolded words.

Comment: With the formatting changes, it's actually an interesting question, and there are three good answers here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's more to an executable binary than being a combination of the machine language of the sources and libraries required, but skipping that for now the answer would still be no: libraries you're linking in are specific to the system they are going to run on. For example, you question mac vs linux... each system has its own way of making calls that trap into the system (for I/O, for example), and if your executable has those items linked into it (rather than through shared objects), you're doomed from the start.

Back to "specific to the system"... not only are things like system calls an issue, but there's more than one executable binary format and this will cause you more than mild pain much of the time. For example, OS X uses the "Mach-O" binary format while Linux uses the "ELF" format. Certainly within these files you'll find similar code for the same executable, but you'll find different binary layouts of that data that make what appears to be straight forward on one system a complete unknown on another. One of many examples... the Mach-O format embeds within the executable the place its dynamically loaded libraries are expected to be -- either absolute locations or locations relative to the loading executable for example. This concept (as far as I know) isn't in either ELF or the Windows "PE" format.

Comment: So what u're saying (correct me if i'm wrong) that during the build phase of the C binary, the fact that i've used standard C library routines like printf or scanf (which is part of any C lib on any platform) wouldn't matter as they further end up calling OS specific system routines which also get involved in the building process. The final output file, if run on a different OS (using the same GCC runtime as the one used to run the executable initially, and same CPU arch) wouldn't have its bindings and linkings (system routines) get resolved coz they would not be located?

Comment: @rahulbsb you've essentially got it. You're calling standard functions but the standardization is in the function signature and operation; there's no standardization across platforms for the implementation which makes these libraries system dependent. The result of bindings and linkings can be both of the problems you describe, even at the same time. There may be some implementation that cannot be bound at the time the program is loaded but worse, its possible to find the right function on a system that uses different encodings, making printf's `write()` call `unlink()`, for example.

Comment: Does that mean code written in interpreted languages like Java when compiled, generate bytecode files which do not include these OS specific system calls besides including standard java APIs or libraries..Then when they go through JVM at runtime they involve all the OS specific system calls.

Comment: Yes it means that exactly. The runtime itself is specific to the system it runs on explicitly so its bytecode can remain independent. (This contributes to the myth of "compile once, run everywhere" though, because there are often other system differences that sometimes lead to problems.)

Comment: By "Mach-O file embedding non-absolute locations" you mean it adds relocatable addresses which later on undergo address translations to get mapped into the Real memory..Right?? Maybe i'm way off with this but are these relocatable addresses parts of the particular program's virtual address space that need to be memory mapped in physical m/m in order to start with final execution..So that means the addresses that the pointers point to aren't virtual addresses but physical addresses.. i'm a bit confused on this.

Comment: Actually I wasn't referring to relocation addresses at all. Rather, I meant the location of dynamic libraries on the file system. Unlike other systems, an OS X Mach-O binary that loads dynamic libraries specifies where these libraries will be found as an addition to environment variables that provide search paths. Those can be absolute paths such as /usr/local/lib/mylib.dylib, or relative path placeholders such as @executable_path/libraries/mylib.dylib (being relative to wherever the executable is), among other placeholders.

Comment: And these dylib files need to be bound to the binary during run-time.Right? ..Or do some of them need to be involved during the linking phase of the build process?? Coz all the C built-in libs bind in the build-phase..So these dylibs also link during build-phase? Maybe not.. coz static libs only are a part of build-phase..Right??

Comment: Dylibs for which the Mach-O path is useful are loaded/linked at run time, but the binary has a small build-time linkage that makes the loader do the runtime work. During the build phase, it's intuitive that static libs are fully linked in. Less clear though is that there is usually a static link (at build time) of a dynamic library to cause the run time loader to do its work -- this removes the responsibility of the programmer from manually opening the dylib and finding symbols within it.

Answer (score 5):

Ignoring the wall of text below line ~10 of your question, some basic reasons why binaries aren't OS independent:

- Each OS has an executable loader which does certain things like load dependent libraries, set the stack pointer etc...
- Even if CPU architecture is the same, the OS architecture is not, and some C library functions are implemented inline, resulting in a specific OS's implementation to be compiled into your executable.
- Function calls might work differently (this is the case for e.g. Windows vs Linux).

All these are really part of an ABI (Application Binary Interface) which is defined by the OS (and sometimes compiler, if the OS implementation is unimplemntable due to e.g. patent issues).

A last reason I can think of:

- The C runtime is different; the Standard leaves a lot of stuff implementation defined, which means a lot of C libraries differ in these respects. In theory, one could implement a portable libc for all OS architectures, but often this is impossible due to hidden details in the OS interface (in the case of Windows or Mac), or structural differences (Linux vs BSD), which ultimately lead to different implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Please also read this [Is C++ platform dependent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810484/why-is-c-platform-dependent)

1. It answers your question
2. It shows you HOW to ask the question