# Importing a GNU/Linux C++ package into Visual Studio on Windows

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-2012

I have no experience with Linux, so this question might seem weird.

I am trying to use a c++ toolbox which has been developed on Debian GNU/Linux Lenny. According to the authors it should work on any recent Linux distribution. However, I need to import it into Visual Studio on Windows.

I have no idea how to get this package configured and built on Visual Studio. I see that there is a "configure" file in the package, but I don't how to use it on Windows. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _"I have no idea how to get this package configured and built on Visual Studio."_ I'm afraid that's not possible this way. If you're lucky you could opt for MinGW and gcc, to get it working on windows.

Comment: Even if you do get the project moved over, you should check that the library is not [platform dependent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810484/why-is-c-platform-dependent). You are being overly optimistic if you think the code will "just work" out of the box.

Comment: this question is off-topic because the OP is asking for a tutorial on how to configure packages

Comment: The `configure` file is from GNU autoconf.  It is a shell script which allows for compatibility on multiple Unixes.  It is probably not applicable to your problem.  If you want to use it in VS, you probably need to set the project up manually.  But, there is another option:  you could use Cygwin, and it will Just Work(tm) with the configure script and Makefile.

Comment: Here is the link to the package: http://www.fransoliehoek.net/docs/madp-0.3.tar.gz

Comment: Ask the authors. They probably know a lot more about their package than we do. Maybe it is just too Unix-specific to even bother to try porting it. Or maybe not. Without knowing the specifics of the package there's no real way to continue. Closing as too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) or [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) to mock a *nix system enough to build most *nix software.  The configure script is generally a (*nix) shell script which will check to see what interfaces and libraries are available to the application during compilation.

Depending on the library you may not be able to use it outside of a unix library, especially if the library depends on the POSIX (*nix) APIs beyond the very small set which Windows provides.

Comment: Cygwin not really. You'll ever need Cygwin installed everywhere the program should run (in contrast to MinGW).

Comment: Possibly true, if you choose to use Cygwin to compile the library you will most likely need to run Cygwin (at least the base DLL) on all target systems.  This is assuming of course that the library itself requires the POSIX interface, at which point you'll need the MinGW library if you choose that route also.  Although MinGW may have a static library at this point.

Answer (score 0):

From your information the package is meant for linux.

This means that if the package contains precompiled code (such as .so or .a - shared libraries / static libraries)you will not be able to run it under windows no matter what (make abstraction of Linux simulated enviroments, I believe you want to run it on a Windows environment).

If the package contains only sources, then you can include  the package inside your solution (I would personally go with a static library approach) and try to compile it. You will get some errors when linux specific headers are included (for example linux threading headers).

After finding the windows equivalent for those functions you will be able to compile and use the package on windows as well.

You basically have to do a manual port.

Comment: The package contains all the source files. When I manually import them into a VS project and try to build it, I get this error message:  
fatal error C1073: Internal error involving incremental compilation(compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\cxxfe\sl\p1\c\p0io.c', line 865)

Comment: Then compile without using incremental compilation :). As mentioned in my answer you will have to do a manual port, meaning treating compiler specific , adding flags in VS environemnt, solving / porting linux specific functions.